# Ruby foreach on last parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreach

I'm new in Ruby and I have a question.

Scenario: I have products, a product belongs to a subcategory and the subcategory belongs to a category. I have multiples products. I want to have a unique list of all subcategory used with their main category. I want to know how to get the data and how to do the `foreach`.

My tables:

```
Table Categories:
id | name
1  |Category1
2  |Category 2
3  |Category 3

Table SubCategories
id|category_id|name
1 |1          |Subcat11
2 |1          |Subcat12
3 |2          |Subcat23
4 |2          |Subcat24
5 |2          |Subcat25
6 |3          |Subcat31


Products
id|subcategory_id|name
1 |3             |Product1
2 |4             |Product2
3 |6             |Product3
```

My models:

```
 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :subCategories
      # attribs: id, name
    end

    class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :category
      # attribs: id, name, continent_id
    end

    class Products < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :Subcategory
      # attribs: id, name, country_id
    end
```

I Want this in my final result

```
Category 2
   Subcat23
   Subcat24
Category 3
   Subcat31
```

So I need help to know how to get this date and how to perform the `foreach` I tried a lots of methods like `includes` and `joins` but that didn't work. Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT 1**
I try Subash solution (edit 1) It almost work, only used main category is show, but all subcategories appear in the list. I also want to hide none used subcategory.

I got this result

```
Category 2
   Subcat23
   Subcat24
   Subcat25
Category 3
   Subcat31
```

In my case, I dont have product with subcategory **Subcat25**. In dont want **Subcat25** in my list.

Here my view

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <% if category.name != "" %>
      <a href="#<%= category.id %>" data-toggle="collapse" class="category">
        <p class="category-title">
        <%= category.name %>
        <i class="fa fa-minus" style="display:none;"></i>
        </p>
      </a>
      <div id="<%= category.id %>" class="collapse items">
        <% category.subcategories.sort_by {|subcategory| subcategory.display_order.to_i}.each do |subcategory| %>
        <p data-intervention-sector="<%= subcategory.id %>">
          <%= subcategory.name %>
        </p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read up on ActiveRecord, you can use Activerecord's eager loading mechanism to do this and avoid any `N+1` query issues,

```
Category.includes(:subcategory).each do |category|
  puts category.subcategory
```

end

[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) is a link to the guides

***EDIT 1***

I'm sure there's a much efficient way to do this using `joins` but I guess here is something that works for now

```
    Category.includes(:subcategory).where(id: Subcategory.where(id: Product.pluck(:subcategory_id).uniq).pluck(:category_id)) do |category|
      puts category
      puts category.subcategories
    end
```

***EDIT 2***

You can try this

```
categories = {}
Product.pluck(:subcategory_id).uniq.each do |subcategory_id|
  sub_cat = Subcategory.includes(:category)
  (categories[sub_cat.category.id] ||= []) << sub_cat
end
```

This line `(categories[sub_cat.category.id] ||= []) << sub_cat` is just adding items to array, if array not found then creates it first and then adds to array,

and you can iterate `categories` and display it however you like.

Comment: I only want to show used subcategory/category by my Products. Your code show all category right? I don't want do display Category 1 and all other subcategory not used in products table.

Comment: if you have million products, you should think again to using `pluck`.

Comment: Thats why I mention to try to do it with `joins`

Comment: It's almost work, only used main category is show, but all subcategories appear in the list. I also want to hide none used subcategory. Look my edit 1 in my main post. Thx :)